# Convergence of inverse of iid uniform random variable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence

I am really struggling with the following problem.
Let
$$X_j  $$ be iid random variable following $U[0,1]$.
Prove that $$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{X_1^{-1}+X_2^{-1}+...+X_n^{-1}}$$ exists almost surely and find its limit.

I really do not know how to apply the strong law of large numbers to the inverse of Uniform variables.
Any help, solution appreciated.

Comment: These are different random variables. It starts with $X_j$ and the limit is about $X$.

Comment: $(\frac 1  {X_i})$ is also i.i.d. Just apply SLLN's to this sequence. Note that this sequence has in finite mean. This implies that the given limit is $0$ a.s.

Comment: Im not sure I see what you mean? Could you give more explanation ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First set $Y=\frac{1}{X}$ and get that

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{y^2}\cdot \mathbb{1}_{[1;+\infty)}(y)$$

With  $\mathbb{E}[Y]=+\infty$

Thus using SLLN you get

$$\overline{Y}_n\xrightarrow{a.s.}\infty$$

and thus

$$\frac{n}{\Sigma_i Y_i}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$$

Comment: Hey Tommik, I thought we could use SLLN only when  [] < +∞?

Comment: @Lola1993 SLLN also works for positive infinite mean, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3742505/strong-law-of-large-numbers-when-the-expectation-is-infinite. Note that it would not necessarily work if $E[ |Y|]=\infty$; a counterexample is the Cauchy distribution.